# MSSQL datetime Field No getting Between Result

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime

I am working a blog web application that having PHP + MSSQL.

**Blogs Table ...**

Pk_blog_id

// Integer PK

Blog_title

// String

Blog_content

// Text

Created_at

// DateTime

I want to collect data from table with months.

my query is.

```
$first_day= date('Y-m-01', $month);   // Getting First day of Month
$last_day = date('Y-m-t', $month);   // Getting Last Day of Month

$sql = "SELECT 
    Pk_blog_id,
    Blog_title,
    Blog_content,
    Created_at 
    FROM dbo.tb_IEAG_Blogs 
    WHERE Is_archived = 0 
    AND Created_at >= CONVERT(datetime,'$first_day') 
    AND Created_at < CONVERT(datetime,'$last_day') 
    ORDER BY tb_IEAG_Blogs.Pk_blog_id DESC";
```

I am not getting result as expected...

When echo the query is like below...

```
SELECT 
 Pk_blog_id,
 Blog_title,
 Blog_content,
 Created_at 
 FROM dbo.tb_IEAG_Blogs 
 WHERE Is_archived = 0 
 AND Created_at >= CONVERT(datetime,'2016-02-01') 
 AND Created_at < CONVERT(datetime,'2016-02-28') 
 ORDER BY tb_IEAG_Blogs.Pk_blog_id DESC
```

Is that is possible the BETWEEN in MSSQL ?

Thanks....

Comment: Try to remove `Is_archived = 0` to test. Of course,using `between` is better.

Comment: **I am not getting result as expected.** So, what is your expected result? Also, give some data from your table is better.

Comment: @Loser,  Its not getting the posts between the given date..

Comment: What is the output you got?

Comment: complete result from table... not filtering date

Comment: Does it work if you explicitly specify the date format: `CONVERT(datetime,'2016-02-28') `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
 Pk_blog_id,
 Blog_title,
 Blog_content,
 Created_at 
 FROM dbo.tb_IEAG_Blogs 
 WHERE Is_archived = 0 
 AND cast(Created_at as date) >= '2016-02-01'
 AND cast(Created_at as date) <'2016-02-28'
 ORDER BY tb_IEAG_Blogs.Pk_blog_id DESC
```

Try this. Because you are comparing the datetime, 2016-02-01 datetime is not equal to your datetime in table.

If you want select the month, here a better SQL for you.

```
   SELECT 
     Pk_blog_id,
     Blog_title,
     Blog_content,
     Created_at 
     FROM dbo.tb_IEAG_Blogs 
     WHERE Is_archived = 0 
     AND DATEPART(MONTH, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATETIME)) = 2
     ORDER BY tb_IEAG_Blogs.Pk_blog_id DESC
```

Comment: You might want to compare the year too, not only the month. Otherweise you get results from every februar in every year.